# replace and lineinfile module does not replace a line

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to configure the WSO2 API manager. I have to change some lines in some xml configuration files.

How do I replace in APIM_HOME/repository/conf/api-manager.xml a line

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
```

with

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://ip-111-111-11.abc.xyz.com:1234,https://ip-111-111-11.abc.xyz.com:{https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
```

I have tried some regex with lineinfile,replace modules & state=present but it is adding the new line to the end of file. I would rather want to replace the existing line with the new line in same position as that of old line.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
- name: "Test lineinfile"
  lineinfile:
    dest: "/etc/ansible/lineinfile.xml"
    state: "present"
    line: "<GatewayEndpoint>http://ip-111-111-11.abc.xyz.com:1234,https://ip-111-111-11.abc.xyz.com:{https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>"
    regexp: "<GatewayEndpoint>"
```

This worked for me and replaced the line

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://${carbon.local.ip}:${http.nio.port},https://${carbon.local.ip}:${https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
```

with the line

```
<GatewayEndpoint>http://ip-111-111-11.abc.xyz.com:1234,https://ip-111-111-11.abc.xyz.com:{https.nio.port}</GatewayEndpoint>
```

Comment: It did worked. This works for this case, because there is only one occurance of <GatewayEndPoint> tag. There are some more cases where the values can be repeated in other lines, too. Hence, I wanted to find the regular expression matching started with ^, (.*), ending with $ etc. The other trick also to simply add a new line (insertafter or insertbefore), and commenting the original line by surrounding the line with <!-- -->. Thanks for sharing your  experience and helping

Comment: In APIM_HOME/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml::::                                               a. <parameter name="HostnameVerifier">AllowAll</parameter>  where <Parameter name...occurs in many places. 
b.<transportReceiver name="http" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOListener">
<parameter name="port" locked="false">8280</parameter>
<transportReceiver name="https" class="org.apache.synapse.transport.nhttp.HttpCoreNIOSSLListener">
<parameter name="port" locked="false">8243</parameter>